# Where do I ask how to learn to do X?

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions, closed-questions

Frequently I find myself wondering how to **learn** to do something that doesn't seem to fall into any obvious category. To be clear, I am not asking for the *best* way to learn it, or for a book/off-site resource, but rather which topics should I look up and understand to reach my goal.

For example, I would like to learn to figure out by myself how exactly C++ lays out the memory at a register level, given the source code for a program and the source code of the compiler used to compile it.

I do not know how to approach this problem, or to which specific domain it belongs. Do I learn assembly? But C++ compilers are not written in assembly. [Computer architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture)? Surely, not the entire field of computer architecture.

Do these questions belong on Stack Overflow despite the following rules?

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an
> entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
> library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
> Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
> Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
> it.

Comment: you may be lucky on chat. But as a question on Stack Overflow, this will be closed, indeed

Comment: Is this because of the rule against off-site resources, or because the scope is too broad? Is there no community on stack-exchange that would answer this question, and why is that?

Comment: "Do I learn assembly? But C++ compilers are not written in assembly.", not sure if I understand the connection.

Comment: Me neither...computers only execute binary instruction codes that match exactly to assembly, (or disassembly), text.  You can watch it 'as it happens' with your debugger. Yes,, you can debug your compiler, (or even debug your debugger:).

Comment: That's the point I was trying to make: I don't know how to approach this problem. Assembly seemed reasonable because I read the parts of a C++ compiler that can't be written in C are written in assembly.

Comment: see also: [Am I right here for basic learning questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364077/839601)

Comment: [Quora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) can be used that way (human search engine after you have exhausted using the normal search engines). The worst that can happen is zero answers (or only snarky ones - just downvote or flag them on the spot). (There is (effectively) only a single sentence for the question, but that is not a problem for very broad questions.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, those kinds of questions do not belong on Stack Overflow, precisely because of those rules.

If you are looking for a place to *start* learning, we're not of much value.  You *could* get someone in chat to point you to something, or you could look at the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) for C++ to get more insights, but ultimately, Stack Overflow is not a resource for when you're literally *just* starting out.